# tcpdump usbmon module output explained

Tags: command-line, usb, serial-port, tcpdump

Running the command:

`tcpdump -qAXni usbmon3 -s 0`

I am getting this output:

```
02:32:04.781964 BULK SUBMIT to 3:16:4
```

What does the last number after the colon (4) represent?
How can I identify it in order to write data to that?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt

Comment: Thnaks, but is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers represent the bus ID, device address and endpoint number. To send/receive USB data from a userspace program you would usually use libusb.

This is the source line which prints these numbers:
https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/c754d30dbd366699ae11ea53655bbef398b83c5c/print-usb.c#L238